# psycopg2: TypeError: Expected bytes or unicode string, got quoted_name instead

Tags: python, pandas, psycopg2

I am trying to load a ~900 MB file to a Postgres database, however the `copy_from` method is causing some issues (the `df.to_sql` method was taking over 8 hours to load this data to AWS).

For example here is some code that converts a dataframe to `stringio`

```
sio = StringIO()
    sio.write(raw_data.to_csv(index=False, header=None, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, sep=','))
    sio.seek(0)

    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        # cur.copy_expert("""COPY sam_monthly_extract_temp FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT CSV)""", sio)
        cur.copy_from(sio, 'sam_monthly_extract_temp', sep=',', columns=load_column_names)
        conn.commit()
```

This is throwing the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sam_monthly_extract.py", line 312, in <module>
    cur.copy_from(sio, 'sam_monthly_extract_temp', sep=',', columns=load_column_names)
TypeError: Expected bytes or unicode string, got quoted_name instead
```

I am at a loss as to what is causing this?  Does it have to do with the `quoting` kwarg in the `to_csv` method?

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Some of the address fields had `,` in them so it was double quoting those fields.  I changed `sep=','` to `sep='|'` in both places and it stopped double quoting the address fields that had `,` in them. However, the problem still persists.

EDIT 2: I got it working with,

```
cur.copy_expert("""COPY sam_monthly_extract_temp FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER '|')""", sio)
```

Comment: I am having the same problem, where do you specify the columns in the second edit ?

Comment: perhaps add `HEADER`  after the with ?

Comment: @moshevi - The file is the same format every month so I just upload it implicitly.  I will post my solution.